# Anyone know what kind of pepper plant this is?

Tags: identification, peppers

The pepper starts out green, then turns purple. [image]

Comment: Good question and illustration; if could include an overall illustration, overall height, leaf size, and mature pepper size, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!